# CSharpCodeProvider: Referencing a different version of referenced assembly

Tags: c#, compilation, appdomain, csharpcodeprovider

Suppose Project `Main` has a reference to Project `Ref`. In `Main`, I have defined a `CSharpCodeProvider` and use it to compile code at runtime.

```
var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
var parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
// Rest of the referenced assemblies.
```

The code which is compiled at runtime, might require a newer version of Project `Ref` to run correctly. So I tried to add the new `Ref.Dll` in a relative subfolder (`plugins`):

```
    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"d:\project-output-path\plugins\Ref.dll");
```

I have also added the following:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath("plugins");
```

Problem is when I try to compile the script dynamically, the `Ref.dll` in the main folder is being used and causes error.

So, What would be the best way to reference the new `Ref` project only for my script?
P.S. I really prefer not having to create another AppDomain since the dynamically executing code is coupled with the code loaded in current AppDomain and cannot be separated.

Comment: That makes little sense, surely you have a problem when you *run* the code.  You already know what to do about it.

Comment: problem is when I compile new code in runtime, I'd like to have the new `Ref` project as reference which is newer than the one referenced in project `Main`. The old `Ref` reference will be used to compile my script in runtime which causes errors. My question is about finding a way to isolate references in my CodeProvider paramaters and use the new `Ref` project.

Comment: Also to be more clear, the code which is being compiled at runtime can vary (so can the version of `Ref` project needed to be referenced in runtime). Basically I'd like to add a new version of a referenced assembly (which resides in a sub-folder) as a reference to my CodeProvider's referenced assemblies in runtime.